# UITableView not showing the right cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 tableViews, the first one is the Main table and the second one is the Favorites table.

Everything is handled with a plist.

From the detailView of the first table, in the upper-right corner, I created a button that writes to the plist the value YES or NO for that cell, so that that specific cell will be shown in the table Favorites.

Now the problem is that:

- I select a row from the first table, the main one. detailView appears and i tap on the UIBarButton making that detail a Favorite (and so a star image appears into the button as an image to let user know that the cell is a favorite). OK.
- I go to the second table, the favorites one, choosing the cell previously favorited and i see that the star is empty, then the bool value is set to NO (and it's supposed to be set to YES due i Favorited it moments ago).

I noticed that if i add to favorites the **first** item of the **firstTable**, then the other cells in the second view are shown correctly, even after i favorited them all in the first view.

A bit tricky, i know, but it's happening.

Any idea why?

The method i'm using for reading the plist is the following:

```
- (NSArray*)readPlist 
{  
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *plistPath = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tipsList.plist"]; 
    NSFileManager *fMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    if (![fMgr fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) { 
        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"list" ofType:@"plist"]; 

    } 

    NSMutableArray *returnArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]; 
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isFav == YES"]; 

    for (NSDictionary *sect in returnArr) { 
        NSArray *arr = [sect objectForKey:@"Rows"]; 
        [sect setValue:[arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] forKey:@"Rows"]; 
    } 
    return returnArr;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

cellForRow:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    NSArray *rows;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        rows = filteredList;
    } else {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isFav == YES"]; 

        NSDictionary *section = [localSortedTips objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        rows = [section objectForKey:@"Rows"];
        [rows filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];        
    return cell;
}
```

And the didSelectRow:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   NSDictionary *section = [localList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSArray *rows = [section objectForKey:@"Rows"];
    NSDictionary *item = [rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        detailViewController *detail = [[detailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailViewController" bundle:nil];
        detail.indexPath = indexPath;
        detail.imageString = [item valueForKey:@"image"]; 
        detail.nameString = [item valueForKey:@"name"];
        detail.title = [item valueForKey:@"name"];
        detail.descriptionString = [item valueForKey:@"description"];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        [detail release];
    }

}
```

**EDIT WITH PICS**

Okay so. I select the **first** row in the **first** section of the mainTable, and the detailView appears:
[image]

Then i favorite it through that little star, setting its value to YES in the plist

[image]

Then I go into the Favorites table, clicking on the previously favorited element and it appears like so

[image]

OK. This works. but only for **this one**!

In fact, if i try to select i.e. a row in the middle of the mainTable, and try to favoriting it, the detailView looks like

[image]

But then, selecting it in the Favorites table looks like so, empty star, while it should be favorited and then filled. If i try to favorite it through the star, and coming back to the Favorites table, the previous row in the mainTable appears, even if it's not favorited.

[image]

I noticed that if i keep the first element, it works fine, but if i remove it, it doesn't work ANYTHING anymore. :\

Any help highly appreciated,stuck from 2 weeks.

Comment: Check your .plist to make sure that the correct yes/no values are being written. The table gets up to some odd behaviors with reusable cells. Basically, AS SOON as a cell is favorited, write the YES value to the .plist. Then, when you're loading a cell for a row, tell the program to check that index in the .plist and set the favorite indication of the cell to the value.

Comment: I just checked the value if it's correctly set, and it is. As soon as i press on the star, the value gets favorited (YES), and as soon as i press again, the value gets to NO. So i guess the problem is in cellForRow?

Comment: Yes, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath read the bool out of the .plist and set the cell's favorite value to whatever it is.

Comment: Above is the cellForRow i have right now. What it's unclear it's how to set the cell's favorite value from cellForRow!

Comment: 1) store the .plist somewhere 2) cell.favorite = [plist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

Comment: Yes i saw that, but it's a bit unclear for me to what i have to do :\ i'm new with plist stuff and it's getting me problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `indexPath` you passing to your `detailController` in `favoritesView` isn't the same like the one in `mainView`. So you have to do some magic to parse the filtered `indexPath` back to the original unfiltered list.

```
- (NSArray*)readPlist // still filtered list
{  
    NSMutableArray *returnArr = [[self readFullPlist] mutableCopy];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isFav == YES"];

    for (NSDictionary *sect in returnArr) {
        NSArray *arr = [sect objectForKey:@"Rows"];
        [sect setValue:[arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] forKey:@"Rows"];
    }

    return returnArr;
}

- (NSArray*)readFullPlist // split that method to get the unfiltered list separately
{
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *plistPath = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tipsList.plist"]; 
    NSFileManager *fMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    if (![fMgr fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) { 
        NSString *bundlePlistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tipsList" ofType:@"plist"];
        [self writePlist:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:bundlePlistPath]];
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
}

- (NSIndexPath*)realIndexPathForIndex:(NSIndexPath*)idxPath
{
    NSArray *fullList = [self readFullPlist];
    NSArray *subArr = [[fullList objectAtIndex:idxPath.section] objectForKey:@"Rows"];

    int row = idxPath.row;
    int newRow = 0;

    for (NSDictionary *dic in subArr)
    {
        if ([[dic valueForKey:@"isFav"] boolValue]) {
            if (row == 0) {
                return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRow inSection:idxPath.section];
            }
            row--;
        }
        newRow++;
    }
    return idxPath;
}
```

Then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you pass this converted `indexPath` instead of the old one:

```
//detail.indexPath = indexPath;
detail.indexPath = [self realIndexPathForIndex:indexPath];
```

Something I want to mention. Instead of using the `indexPath` you should use an unique identifier if possible. This would make things (like this one) much easier because you only pass that `id` to the next controller.

Comment: Thanks, i'll take that suggestion as a treasure!

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with things like this with custom table cells. Usually the problem is in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Because you say it gives you the first cell back, I would guess that you're reusing your cells. It doesn't matter which one you tell it to load, if you're reusing cells xcode will just throw the first cell in that it thinks is suitable. Here's how to get rid of the problem:

```
//Returns a cell to be used at a row, populates it from the holder object
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    NSArray *tempPlist = [self readPlist];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UITableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.favorite = [tempPlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Kay, the problem is that cell.favorite doesn't exists, i mean, it's a property of the detailView! It has the UIBarButtonItem on the top-right corner with that star image which indicates wether the detailView is favorited or not.

Comment: Right, since I don't have your code for what makes something a favorite or not I just used cell.favorite. The point is, take whatever indicates that the cell is a "favorite" and immediately assign the boolean value to it.

Comment: Then the "isFav" key of the plist in this case

Comment: No, what thing that is not in the .plist (that is a property of the cell itself) indicates whether it is a favorite?

Comment: The detailView has that upper right corner button, that states whether is favorite or not!

Comment: Can you post some pictures/code from this problem? I'm confused as to what is actually happening. detailView has to be getting it's information from somewhere; where is it getting it from?

Comment: Updated the question with images

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13123/discussion-between-cake-and-pheel)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, You have two table views. one is main Table  and second one is favorite table. If you select the favorite icon in the main table, need to change the key value in plist to `YES` and need to reload both the tables. is this right?

if yes, you have to follow the following steps.

> 1. are the both table view cells are same? if no, please differentiate it in cellForRowAtIndexPath:.
> 2. are you updating the favorite key value in plist? while selecting the favorite button. According to your code it seems to be NO.
> 3. once you have updated the plist, need to reload the both (main table & favorite table) the tables. are you reloading the tables? you
>      are not reloading the table in your code because you have written this
>      after return statement.

please check these conditions and let me know if you have any other prospective.

I think this may helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks. So, the cells are the same (filtered by that favoriting value,though). The value is being updated, in the question there's not the writing code.
For the plist thing, where do i need to reload them?

Comment: I think you have to reload the tables in ViewWillAppear:.

Comment: In the favorites table i reload it in viewWillAppear, in the other one not, since it's beign reloaded on Refresh  (downloading a plist from remote)

Comment: Have you checked that, whenever you select the favorite icon in the main table, are you update the key as YES in the plist and once you have completed the writing plist file you need to navigate to the next screen. So that, you can see these modifications in the favorite table.

Answer (score 0):

No were in your readPlist method do you say which isFav to read.  So even though all rows/cells have their own entries in the plist you are not getting the specific isFav for that specific row

Comment: The readPlist method only shows the cells with isFav set to YES!

Comment: ah yes i see now, i had it backwards