# Delete cell in tableView with Plist

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, plist

I want to delete a cell in one of my 2 tableViews (1 is the main one, 2 the Favorites one).

To delete a cell, i should set a specific value to "NO", in order to be NO in the plist (the Favorite table shows only cells with "isFav" value set to YES).

Check this question for further details: [UITableView not showing the right cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157692/uitableview-not-showing-the-right-cells)

Back to my question, i tried to do

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    NSArray *plist = [self readPlist];
    NSMutableDictionary *theItem = [[[plist objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"Rows"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",theItem);
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [theItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isFav"]; 

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[[[NSArray arrayWithObject:[plist objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]valueForKey:@"Rows"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

        [self writePlist:plist];   
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
}


- (void)writePlist:(NSArray*)arr 
{ 
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *plistPath = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tipsList.plist"]; 
    NSFileManager *fMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    if ([fMgr fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) 
        [fMgr removeItemAtPath:plistPath error:nil]; 

    [arr writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES]; 
}

- (NSArray*)readPlist 
{  
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *plistPath = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tipsList.plist"]; 
    NSFileManager *fMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    if (![fMgr fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) { 
        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tipsList" ofType:@"plist"]; 

    } 

    NSMutableArray *returnArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]; 
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isFav == YES"]; 

    for (NSDictionary *sect in returnArr) { 
        NSArray *arr = [sect objectForKey:@"Rows"]; 
        [sect setValue:[arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] forKey:@"Rows"]; 
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } 
    return returnArr;

}
```

but with no success. 
What was i trying to do: trying to get to the current item in the table, then set its "isFav" value to NO and then delete the cell from the table, but i'm failing, getting

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd4ab0'
```

I tried to do `[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]` but i get

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Any help appreciated :|

Comment: It looks like you're trying to reference the property `row` on your dictionary. Since it doesn't have this property you get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error occurs because the `dataSource` count isn't the same like the actual data. When you delete an item the `tableView` cells will go down eg. from 10 to 9. But you didn't delete the data from your `dataSource` so you end up with different `count` and Xcode poke you a little.

As talked (extensively) in chat we got the problem solved with this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [tableView beginUpdates];

        NSIndexPath *realIndex = [self realIndexPathForIndex:indexPath];
        NSArray *plist = [self readFullPlist];

        NSMutableDictionary *theItem = [[[plist objectAtIndex:realIndex.section] valueForKey:@"Rows"] objectAtIndex:realIndex.row];
        [theItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isFav"];
        [self writePlist:plist];

        [self refreshTable];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
}

- (NSArray*)readFullPlist
{
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *plistPath = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tipsList.plist"]; 
    NSFileManager *fMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    if (![fMgr fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) { 
        NSString *bundlePlistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tipsList" ofType:@"plist"];
        [self writePlist:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:bundlePlistPath]];
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
}

- (NSIndexPath*)realIndexPathForIndex:(NSIndexPath*)idxPath
{
    NSArray *fullList = [self readFullPlist];
    NSArray *subArr = [[fullList objectAtIndex:idxPath.section] objectForKey:@"Rows"];

    int row = idxPath.row;
    int newRow = 0;

    for (NSDictionary *dic in subArr)
    {
        if ([[dic valueForKey:@"isFav"] boolValue]) {
            if (row == 0) {
                return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRow inSection:idxPath.section];
            }
            row--;
        }
        newRow++;
    }
    return idxPath;
}
```

Comment: Where does refreshTable link to ?

Comment: in this case it's a function which creates a server connection to gather the data, apply some sorting, update UI and then calls `reloadData` on the table view. In the easiest way this will be like loading data from somewhere and then call `[tableView reloadData];`

Answer (score 0):

In you tableView: commitEditingStyle: method, look up the statement where you want to delete the rows in the tableView. Here you should hand over an array with NSIndexPaths. This line is very hard to read in your snippet since it contains many nested calls...

Comment: Well in that line i try to get to the correct element (in order to avoid to remove unwanted cells). What should the NSIndexPaths array contain if i handle the table with plist?

Comment: You probably probably only want to delete the cell which was passed in to delete with the indexpath, so take `[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]` to delete exactly that cell from your table. Additionally you want to wrap the change of iSFav on your object from the plist and the deletion of the cell in `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]`. You don't need the `[tableView reloadData]` as well.

Comment: I edited my question, tried that way too, but always getting errors! Shouldn't i reload the table at the end?

Comment: No, this will reload the table completely. You don't want that.

Comment: I don't know how the rest of you datasource implementation looks like, but make sure that the changes you are in there when you delete the row.